# How to disable plugins on Foxit Reader?

Tags: pdf, plugins, foxit-reader

I'm using Foxit Reader to read PDFs on my Windows 8, and sometimes it crashes. According to the crash message, it crashed because of a specific plugin installed on it. When I go to *Help* -> *About Foxit Plug-ins* I can see the plugin's name, but there is no option to disable it there. I'd like to disable this plugin. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. Actually, the only solution that I found was to delete/move  *.fpi files (which are the files related to the plug-ins). Then close and re-open Foxit.

They can be found at --> "C:\Program Files (86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\plugins"

Regards.